# What does alert(document.cookie) in logs tell you?

Tags: symfony, security, cookies

I see log below in my symfony project sometimes and I cannot find out from where I get this log and how to reproduce it:

```
 request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception UnexpectedValueException: "Invalid Host "<img src="" onerror="alert(document.cookie)">"" at /app/bootstrap.php.cache line 933 {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Invalid Host \"<img src=\"\" onerror=\"alert(document.cookie)\">\" at /app/bootstrap.php.cache:933, UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Invalid Host \"<img src=\"\" onerror=\"alert(document.cookie)\">\" at /app/bootstrap.php.cache:933)"} []
 request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (UnexpectedValueException: Invalid Host "<img src="" onerror="alert(document.cookie)">" at /app/bootstrap.php.cache line 933) {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Invalid Host \"<img src=\"\" onerror=\"alert(document.cookie)\">\" at /app/bootstrap.php.cache:933)"} []
```

How can I reproduce this log? and is it something I should be worry about?

Comment: The users or boots of your site inject malicious code, have you any forms without csrf token, did you properly escaped html tags in forms posted by users?

Comment: I know something like this should have happened but how can I log more data to see which form is doing this?

Comment: How you want to log it? Isn't better to prevent it?

Comment: I am not sure how to identify what area are vulnerable so I can prevent it

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? I am experiencing a similar issue in my application. This is the error I see in my logs: `{"message":"[2016-12-09 08:07:58] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception UnexpectedValueException: \"Invalid Host \"52.1.11.241 crmpicco.co.uk\"\" at /var/www/crmpicco/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 931 {\"exception\":\"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Invalid Host \\\"52.1.11.246 crmpicco.co.uk\\\" at /var/www/crmpicco/app/bootstrap.php.cache:931)\"} {\"token\":\"-1de2c3c2\"}","hostname":"CRMPicco [2016-11-14]"}`

Comment: no luck on my side!